# NGINX - Reverse Proxy Issues. Not re-writing URLS? I think?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I expect I am doing something just simply incorrect here. Essentially I have 3 apps that I have configured a NGINX reverse proxy for. Each one seems to start to load but what I think is happening is something wrong with the re-write. So I can see in chrome network trace each load the first item ok but then instead of example.com/app1/applicationdirx it attempts example.com/applicationdirx (this returns a 404 for every item it tries to load) This is happening for all 3 apps running on seperate machines. So I expect its my config somewhere. Please dont judge my config. I have spent hours and hours playing with it so its a bit of a mess. haha. I would assume its proxy_redirect but I have tried every combination (including default and off with no avail). If i change the location to root "/" and update the config accordingly, the apps work fine. its just when I am trying to do it under /app1/,/app2/ and /app3/ it doesnt. :(

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
çmap $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}



server {

 set $app1 192.168.5.3:443;
 set $app2 192.168.5.3:8443;
 set $app3 192.168.5.79:8123;


**app1*

  location /app1/ {
    proxy_pass https://$app1/;
    proxy_redirect https://$app1 https://$server_name/app1/;
proxy_cache off;
    proxy_store off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Referer "";

    client_max_body_size 0;
  }


## app2 ##

location /app2/
{
proxy_pass https://$app2/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect https://$app2/ https://$server_name/app2/;

}

## app3##
   location /app3/ {
   proxy_pass http://$app3/;
                  proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #proxy_redirect http://$app3 https://$server_name/app3;
        proxy_redirect http://192.168.5.79:8123/ https://$server_name/app3/;
       # proxy_redirect off;

proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        #proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }

    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullcapp3in.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```